# Converting file to key/value dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am unsure if what I have is actually creating a new dictionary. I want to take a file that currently has two words separated by commas on each line and turn it into a dictionary with the first word being the key and the second being the value. I see that if I print, the words are separated but I am unsure if it is returned correctly. Thanks

```
WDictionary = open('file.csv', 'r')
for line in WDictionary:
    mylist = line.split(',')
    return mylist
```

Comment: I think your indentation is off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dict(line.split(',') for line in WDictionary)
```

Edit: as suggested

```
dict(line.strip().split(',') for line in WDictionary)
```

Comment: might want to throw a `map(str.strip, line.split(','))` there to get rid of the newline

Comment: Getting rid of the newline is a good idea, but in my opinion `dict(line.strip().split(',') for line in WDictionary)` is clearer than using map. For getting rid of internal whitespace, the `map` version might be better (if that's desired).

Comment: Since you're new--the syntax the answer is using is called a dict comprehension.  It's a shorthand way of iterating through the WDictionary and adding the result of each line to a new dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [CSV](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

They already solved the problem you are trying to solve, including quoting issues, iterating over lines, and parsing it out :)

You can try something like this for your code:

```
import csv
def readACSV():
    with open('file.csv', 'r') as WDictionary
    reader = csv.reader(WDictionary)
    for row in reader:
         yield row

for line in readACSV():
    print line
```

Dont know if that helps, but a little usage example in case you were unsure how to use it.

Comment: What's the purpose of the second example, as opposed to directly iterating over the reader? Even if you want to isolate opening the file, just return the reader directly from `readACSV` rather than unnecessarily wrapping another generator around it.

Comment: You are correct, I was trying to fit it into the OP's example