# Word Dictionary Problems

Tags: python

I have a starting file which has values on each line separated by a comma, like so:

```
hello,welcome
hi, howareyou
hola,comoestas
```

I want to take those words and put them into a dictionary so they are key/value pairs. Then i am trying to ask for a key and return the corresponding value. I believe i am close so any help would be appreciated. Also i am a beginner so simple code is best.

```
def CreateDictionary():


     WordDictionary = open('file.csv', 'r')
     for line in WordDictionary:
         mylist = line.split(',')
         return(mylist)


def main():

     cd = CreateDictionary()
     text=input('input text:')
     for x in cd.values():
        if x == text:
            word=cd[x]
            print(word)

main()
```

Comment: So a) you asked a [question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304591/converting-file-to-key-value-dictionary) a few minutes ago and haven't used either of the answers here and b) it would help if you could explain in your question what you expect to happen and what is actually happening

Comment: I get the feeling s/he was confused by the answers--they were a little advanced (although good.)  @user2844776, feel free to ask for clarification as a comment in the given answer (although the Python docs will also be of a big help--learning to read those is a huge part of becoming a good developer.)

Comment: I did ask a related question earlier and the answer i got was a little over my head and it produced an error. Im looking to input 'hello' and get 'welcome' printed for example. Right now i am getting an "attribute error: list object has no attribute values"

Answer (score 1):

```
def makeDict(infilepath):
  answer = {}
  with open(infilepath) as infile:
    for line in infile:
      key,val = line.strip().split(',')
      answer[key] = val
    return answer

def main(infilepath):
  cd = makeDict(infilepath)
  key = input('input text: ')
  if key in cd:
    print(cd[key])
  else:
    print("'%s' is not a known word" %key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you could edit your solution to create a dictionary.

```
def CreateDictionary():
    ret_dict = {}
    with open('file.csv', 'r') as WordDictionary:
        for line in WordDictionary:
            parts = line.split(',')
            ret_dict[parts[0]] = parts[1]
    return ret_dict


def main():
    cd = CreateDictionary()
    text = raw_input('input text:')
    word = cd[text]
    print word

main()
```

A main issue with your approach is that you have `return` inside of a for loop. The function will return after the first loop iteration and will not continue beyond the first line of the file.